# Installing a bash program on mac

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell

Hi all I am trying to install a bash program called objconv which converts object files between different architectures on my macbook air. I have so far followed the instructions but when I successfully install the script file and attempt to the command for the program terminal gives me the error `-bash: objconv: command not found` I have tried everything I know to fix it but nothing has worked. I also installed homebrew using instructions on a thread on this website. I currently have version 4.3.___ installed. I have my bash directory set to this `/usr/local/bin/bash`
 as per the homebrew instructions stated and I have stated in the top of the build.sh file like: `#!/usr/local/bin/bash`.

This is the download to the objconv file which as the instructions:

> http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv.zip

Here is the pdf file with the instructions please refer to page 4:

> http://www.agner.org/optimize/objconv-instructions.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `objconv` tool, but it seems as though `bash` simply cannot find it wherever you have installed it. That means your PATH is probably wrong because that tells `bash` where programs are to be found.

So, first, you need to find `objconv`, and I am guessing you are unsure where it is. Let's try looking in `/usr/local` like this

```
find /usr/local -name objconv -type f
```

and if that doesn't work, broaden your search to the whole of `/usr` like this

```
find /usr -name objconv -type f
```

and if that doesn't work, try searching your entire Mac, like this, which will be slower

```
sudo find / -name objconv -type f 2> /dev/null
```

The outpt of the above search(es) will be like

```
/usr/local/bin/bash/objconv
```

which would mean that the `objconv` program is in the directory `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

If you now want to run it, you can either type

```
/usr/local/bin/bash/objconv [something] ... <something>
```

or, if that is too long-winded, edit your `bash` profile in `$HOME/.profile` and change the line that sets the PATH so it looks like:

```
export PATH=WhereverObjconvLives:$PATH
```

Then activate the new PATH using:

```
source $HOME/.profile
```

Comment: So none of the first 2 commands you gave me returned anything however the entire mac search found files of similar names however none of which are in a bash folder rather just where the file is located on my macbook. 

`/Users/---/.Trash/objconv
/Users/----/.Trash/objconv 11.16.56 am/source/objconv
/Users/------/.Trash/source/objconv
/Users/-----/Desktop/------/-------/task/objconv/objconv
/Users/-----/Desktop/-------/-----/task/objconv/source/objconv
`

Comment: When I run the build.sh file using the ./build.sh command it makes a c program called objconv in the same folder however when I go to open it it shows me the instructions for the program and then stops.

Comment: Please don't put lots of code and program output in comments - it is really hard to read - it is better to click `edit` under your original question and add extra details and program output there.

Comment: If you run `objconv` and it tells you the instructions, it is working! You need to add the parameters now to tell it what you want it to do.

Comment: But the problem is once the instructions show up it ends the program `logout _____` an doesnt allow me to write any parameters. It requires me to use a command window and start with `objconv .......`

Comment: I don't know the `objconv` program, but such behaviour is pretty normal for a Unix commandline program - that is normally how they work.

Comment: I know this may be a long shot but is there anychance that you can try running the program on your computer if you have a macbook? There is a windows version however when I run the exe a command window opens and then shows the same thing I get on my macbook and nothing else. Alternatively would you know how I can convert a `ELF` version of a object file into a `MACHO` or a windows readable format?

Comment: Sorry, I can't and don't :-)